# Should I use Sleep in my PHP cron job

Tags: php, resources, cron

I have a PHP script as a cron job that runs every 5 mins, and in the script, it makes a query to the database and loop through the records:

```
$results = DB::query("SELECT id FROM category");

foreach ($results as $row) {

    // process the data, save data the a local file or database

    // should I have Sleep here?
}
```

Should I add a Sleep in the end of the loop? Because I am wondering if I don't make a sleep call there, the server (which is also a web server) would be tied up when this PHP runs? (There are other requests that the server has to take care of while the PHP script runs)

Comment: A sleep call isn't taking up any noticeable processor while it sleeps, though it will still have a certain amount of memory allocated; but if you sleep in that loop, you'll be holding record locks.... but why do you need a sleep at that point?

Comment: just like in C programming, calling Sleep() in a loop will yield the CPU resources to other processes/threads.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a sleep, which, as mentioned by @MarkBaker in the Comments still holds memory and record locks, consider packaging your cron jobs into smaller pieces of work.

Just do one of your checks per cronjob (delete old sessions, delete outdated, inactive users, etc.tt.).

That will keep the server alive while still doing all your jobs.

Comment: Inside the loop, I have to make another network request to other server & write back to the same database.

Comment: but can't you do that in chunks as well? paginate your request to said server thus paginate your writing to your servers database?